# Show $\sum_n \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}} = \frac{z}{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}} = \frac{z}{1-z}$ for $|z|<1$.

This is an additional problem for my complex analysis class and I've attempted it for a few hours but ended up taking wrong routes. All of my attempts I haven't used complex analysis at all and I don't see how I could here.

edit: this is meant for a BEGINNER complex analysis course so please try keep the solutions to that (if you could)

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{z}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^4}{1-z^8}+\cdots$$

Add $\displaystyle \frac{-z}{1-z}$ to both sides. It's [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series):

$$\frac{-z}{1-z}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{-z}{1-z}+\frac{z}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^4}{1-z^8}+\cdots=\\ =\frac{-z-z^2}{1-z^2}+\frac{z}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^4}{1-z^8}+\cdots= \\ = \frac{-z^2}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^4}{1-z^8}+\cdots= \\ = \frac{-z^4-z^2}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^4}{1-z^8}+\cdots=\frac{-z^4}{1-z^4}+\frac{z^4}{1-z^8}+ \cdots$$

$\textbf{Edit:}$ If you want to have finite sum rather than infinity. You can show that (like above - by cancelling terms) :

$$\frac{-z}{1-z}+\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{-z^{2^{m}}}{1-z^{2^{m}}}$$

Next calculate limit for $m \to \infty$ both sides.

$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{-z}{1-z}+\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{-z}{1-z}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}$$

Finally (because $|z|<1$):
$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{-z^{2^{m}}}{1-z^{2^{m}}}=0$$

Comment: I appreciate this response, but is there any way to justify the cancellations as we are summing to infinity rather than a finite number

Comment: I've replaced infinity sum by finite summation.

Answer (score 1):

The first term is $z/(1-z^2)$ which is a series where every exponent is odd.
What are the exponents in the series of the second term?

Comment: This shows that the odd parts of the left and right hand sides coincide, but I don't see how does it answer the question. And especially how does this use complex analysis.

Comment: The second term gives singly-even exponents.  The third term gives doubly-even exponents.  Eventually all exponents occur once on each side.  Beginner complex analysis courses can't use much complex analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\displaystyle F(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}$. Put $\displaystyle G(z)=F(z)-\frac{z}{1-z}$. Compare $G(z)$ and $G(z^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> Every integer $k\geqslant1$ can be written in one and only one way as $k=2^n+i2^{n+1}=2^n(1+2i)$, for some $n\geqslant0$ and $i\geqslant0$.

To apply the hint, note that, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=z^{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(z^{2^{n+1}}\right)^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty z^{2^n+i2^{n+1}},$$ hence the sum on $n\geqslant0$ of the LHS is the sum of $z^k$ on $k\geqslant1$, that is, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k=\frac{z}{1-z}.$$

This only uses (but twice) the expansion $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k.$$
To prove the hint, note that each integer $k\geqslant1$ is $k=2^np$ where $p$ is odd and positive and $2^n$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing $k$, that is, $k=2^n(1+2i)$ for some $i\geqslant0$, which proves simultaneously the existence and the uniqueness of this factorization.

Comment: I'm not sure how you applied the hint in the first line, i.e. the first equality : $\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=z^{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(z^{2^{n+1}}\right)^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty z^{2^n+i2^{n+1}},$

Comment: The equality you cite does not use the hint but the expansion of every geometric series recalled just later on. The hint is used to sum all these contributions.

Comment: I really don't see how you got that expression though, I've been trying to see how you equated them could you please show me

Comment: Use the geometric expansion for $x=z^{2^{n+1}}$ and multiply the resulting series by $z^{2^n}$.

Comment: oh I see... That's interesting - what was your motivation?

Comment: ?? Answering the question (what else?).